# how to send image as attachment with web service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, sharpziplib

I want to add new employee to web service.
The employee photo should be sent as an attachment with the web service.
and sent as a password protected ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for your image and send as a stream as follows,

You have to add the stream conversion for each image and add the details to a list.

in the client side.

```
Stream stream = (Stream)openDialog.File.OpenRead();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    {
                        bmi.SetSource(ms);
                        newRow.Thumbnail = bmi;
                }
```

in your service side

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ImageUploadPath");

                          if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
                          {
                              Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                          }

                          filePath = filePath + "\\" + picture.FileName + "." + picture.FileType;

                          if (picture.FileName != string.Empty)
                          {
                              fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                              writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
                              writer.Write(picture.FileStream);
                          }
```